# Browse for folder in AIR on Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I am trying the follow, but it appears to be not working piece of code on Android, only it does work on Desktop applications.

```
var f : File = new File;
    f.addEventListener( Event.SELECT, onFolderSelected );
    f.browseForDirectory( "Select home directory" );
```

- How to browse for folder under Android ?

*( Flex 4.6, AIR application )*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`browseForDirectory` is not working for android, this is explicitly said in documentation.

So, you have to implement your own selection dialog.

You can see example of implementation here:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4107990#4107990

However, if you want to see standard android dialog, you will have to work with native extensions.

Comment: Thank You. I didn't notice it at first place.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an [ANE](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) for that.